# WPF TabControl - Add New Tab With Content Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a demo application to help me understand WPF/MVVM. I have been struggling for 3 days looking at various tutorials and threads. I want to make a tab control with a new tab button (like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)) that lets the user create a new tab with specified content template. I create my user control that I want to be the template here:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MvvmTest.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListView d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

It is just a control with a ListView. So, I want this ListView to be in any new tab that is opened.

Here is my main window with the actual tab control:

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="New Tab" Margin="703,6,10,401" Click="Button_Click"/>

        <TabControl Name= "TabControl1" Margin="0,33,0,-33" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In this code-behind, I try to create a new tab programmatically and set the content template to the new control.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl1.Items.Add(new TabItem() { ContentTemplate = UserControl1 });
}
```

This fails. I also tried setting properties in the XAML which also failed. I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to use MVVM, where is your view model? The approach you have so far is not very MVVM because you're using code-behind to add tab items. The MVVM approach would be to bind the `ItemSource` property of the `TabControl` to a collection of items and let the view model add the items for you. You also cannot use a `UserControl` as a `ContentTemplate` like that without wrapping it in a `DataTemplate` definition.

The first thing to do is to define some view models:

```cs
// MvvmLight (from NuGet) is included for it's INotifyPropertyChanged
// (ViewModelBase) and ICommand (RelayCommand) classes. INotifyPropertyChanged
// is how Binding works between the View and the View Model. You could 
// implement these interfaces yourself if you wanted to. 
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;


namespace MvvmTest
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        // store our list of tabs in an ObservableCollection
        // so that the UI is notified when tabs are added/removed
        public ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel> Tabs { get; }
            = new ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel>();

        // this code gets executed when the button is clicked
        public ICommand NewTabCommand 
            => new RelayCommand(() => Tabs.Add(new TabItemViewModel() 
               { Header = $"Tab {Tabs.Count + 1}"})); 
    }

    public class TabItemViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        // this is the title of the tab, note that the Set() method
        // invokes PropertyChanged so the view knows if the 
        // header changes
        public string Header
        {
            get => _header;
            set => Set(ref _header, value);
        }
        private string _header;

        // these are the items that will be shown in the list view
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } 
            = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    }
}
```

Then you can fix your XAML so that it refers to the view-models that you defined. This requires defining the `DataContext` for your MainWindow and binding the elements of MainWindow to properties on the view model:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MvvmTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <!--Set the DataContent to be an instance of our view-model class -->
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--The Command of the button is bound to the View Model -->
        <Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100"  
                Content="New Tab" 
                Command="{Binding NewTabCommand}" />

        <!--ItemsSource is bound to the 'Tabs' property on the view-
            model, while DisplayMemeberPath tells TabControl 
            which property on each tab has the tab's name -->
        <TabControl Grid.Row="1" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" 
                    DisplayMemberPath="Header">

            <!--Defining the ContentTemplate in XAML when is best.
                This template defines how each 'thing' in the Tabs 
                collection will be presented. -->
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--The UserControl/Grid were pointless, so I 
                        removed them. ItemsSource of the ListView is 
                        bound to an Items property on each object in
                        the Tabs collection-->
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Some column"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The result is that when you press the button, a new tab gets created and shown

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, John. I watched a tutorial on MVVM last night after I posted this thread, and the author claimed that "there is no point in using MVVM unless you want to write unit-testable code" Do you agree with this notion? WPF/MVVM clearly has a massive learning curve. Secondly and more relevant to this thread, the original intent was to make a file explorer (like the one built into windows) with a 'new tab' feature. This way, you could have multiple views open and switch between them. That would mean each tab/view would have it's own ItemsSource as the list of files/folders, right?

Comment: @MemeMachine WPF is designed with MVVM in mind. Usually a high level framework will always implement certain design patterns as they are well designed to make them a useful and reliable tool. Since a framework follows the IoC principle, the patterns extent to the client code. Although WPF allows to be used without adhering to the MVVM pattern, your code will become easier to write and to maintain. For example, MVVM is data *model centered*. Handling data items is far more convenient then struggling to obtain and handle UI elements.

Comment: @MemeMachine For example adding item containers like TabItem directly to the ItemsControl will disable performance features like UI virtualization. You should add data models instead and let WPF create the containers for you. The disadvantages of writing UI centered code will become more apparent the more complex your application becomes. For small applications it's fine to mix view model and model, but it can be only to your advantage to know how to implement MVVM properly.

Comment: @MemeMachine MVVM is more than just unit test ready code, for sure. I also believe that any structure is better than no structure. So either develop a MVVM structured application or a chaos application without any structure. At least try to implement the SOLID principles. Also your code does not follow the MVVM pattern. I highly recommend learning WPF properly which means to learn and understand MVVM. Instead of completly abandon it, learn it and then once you understand it you can decide how strict you want to implement MVVM. Just be patient.

Comment: @BionicCode Alright, I'll give it another shot. It's just very frustrating. Is there any sehr good source that you recommend to learn MVVM properly? There appears to be a lot of misinformation, like the thing I told you about.

Comment: @MemeMachine Yes, there are a lot of bad and even wrong tutorials out there. It's best to understand the idea of patterns like MVVM, MVC and MVP. It's better to understand the fundamental ideas instead of following tutorials. Tutorials are more focused on *how* to do something and not on *why*. If you understand the *why*, you will have an easy time to implement things without tutorials. MVVM is very simple. Just try to understand the idea and what the three components are about. Once it clicks, everything will feel natural. And try to stay within the Microsoft Docs ecosystem for correct infos